# dynamically create,compile and import msg files

Tags: ros, rospy, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i'm trying to create and dynamically compile msg files to use them while the node is running.
Somehow it works only for the first msg file which i create,compile and import.
Every file which i try to import after the first one gets an import error.

Here is a very simple example of what im trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PKG = 'janus'
msgPath = "/home/jan/Desktop/Janus/trunk/janus/msg" #my Path to the msg folder

import os
import codecs
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PKG)

os.chdir(msgPath)

fobj = codecs.open("test"+".msg", 'w')
fobj.write("float32 buttons")
fobj.close()
exec('os.system("rosmake %s")' %PKG)
exec('from %s.msg import test' %PKG)

fobj1 = codecs.open("test1"+".msg", 'w')
fobj1.write("float32 buttons")
fobj1.close()
exec('os.system("rosmake %s")' %PKG)
exec('from %s.msg import test1' %PKG)
```

So why it imports the first file, but not the second? :(
hope you can help me
thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10440/dynamically-create,compile-and-import-msg-files/) by [jduewel](https://answers.ros.org/users/769/jduewel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to reload the Python module.  After the first call, Python has loaded 'janus' and will not go back out to disk.

http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/functions.html#reload

Note: in general, you have to be careful when calling reload as it can result in inconsistent modules.  It should be fine if you are just fetching msg files.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-29**:
From your code, it looks like 'janus' is the module.

**Comment by [jduewel](https://answers.ros.org/users/769/jduewel/) on 2011-06-29**:
Ive read the manual carefully, but i still dont know which module to reload.